# Assemblies referencing multiple versions of some .NET libraries

Tags: c#, .net, clr, static-analysis, decompiling

When I decompile my assemblies in JustDecompile, I find that they are referencing multiple versions of some .NET libraries.

Here is an example (`mscorlib`, `System.Drawing` and `System.Windows.Forms` are referenced twice):

```
mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0
mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0
System, Version=4.0.0.0 
System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0
System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0
System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0
System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0
System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0
System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0
```

Can someone give me an explanation as to why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would happen if they write a .Net 4.0 application that uses a third-party library build for .Net 2.0.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  My third-party library also references `System.Data, v2.0.0.0`.  Is there a reason why this isn't represented above like the rest?